# How to hide or disable Cancel button in WIX Installer?

Tags: c++, wix, custom-action, windows-installer

I am new to WiX installer. I need to **Hide** or **disable** the **cancel button** in WIX installer when progress bar is running.

I have googled but did not find some useful link to hide the cancel button. I found this: [**Hiding the Cancel Button During an Installation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Msi/hiding-the-cancel-button-during-an-installation), but still have no idea how to use a custom action. Is there anyone who can give me some guidance to achieve this?

I have done the following things to hide the cancel button but it's not working.
First of all, i have written a custom action in C++ according to mentioned link above. Let me show what i did for custom action.

Open visual studio -> Create new project -> custom action in C++ selected and select type DLL.

It will create a new project with cpp file. I named the cpp file as custom action and write the below code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shellapi.h>
#include <msi.h>
#include <Msiquery.h>


UINT __stdcall HideCancelButton(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    PMSIHANDLE hRecord = MsiCreateRecord(2);
    if (!hRecord)
        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiRecordSetInteger(hRecord, 1, 2)
        || ERROR_SUCCESS != MsiRecordSetInteger(hRecord, 2, 0))
        return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;

    MsiProcessMessage(hInstall, INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA, hRecord);

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}


// DllMain - Initialize and cleanup WiX custom action utils.
extern "C" BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
    __in HINSTANCE hInst,
    __in ULONG ulReason,
    __in LPVOID
    )
{
    switch(ulReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        WcaGlobalInitialize(hInst);
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        WcaGlobalFinalize();
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

This is the .def file code:

```
LIBRARY "HideCancelButton"

EXPORTS
    HideCancelButton
```

Now i build the project and it's created the HideCancelButton.dll file.

Now come to my WIX project.
Add custom action:

```
 <Binary Id="HideCancelButtonDll" SourceFile="C:\Users\umer\Desktop\HideCancelButton.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="CAhidecancel" BinaryKey="HideCancelButtonDll" Execute="immediate" Impersonate="no" DllEntry="HideCancelButton" Return="check"/>
```

Add following line in install execution sequence

```
 <Custom Action='CAhidecancel' Before='CreateSSISCatalog'></Custom>
```

That's all i have done but it's not working. I checked the log and it shows that return value is 1. But still cancel button is showing. To check whether function is calling or not i put sleep(10000) and show status on installer and it was working as expected but cancel button is showing.

Answer (score 2):

### Hiding Cancel Button

The link you found is the most authoritative that can be found. It says it all, but let me summarize here for any future user who finds this.

Before doing so, we have to ask why you need this? It might indicate a problem that should be solved in some other way to be avoided properly.

***How to hide the Cancel button during an MSI installation?***

1. ***msiexec.exe:*** You can hide the **`Cancel`** button by installing with the **`!`** command line option specified when doing a basic user interface level installation: **`msiexec.exe /I Setup.msi /QB-!`**. You can deliver a batch file along with your MSI to install like this, or configure it in your distribution system (SCCM or similar).
2. ***Windows Installer API*** (running outside MSI): You can invoke the installation via [MSI API COM automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/automation-interface-reference) (VBScript & other scripts) or [MSI API Win32 installer functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/msi/installer-function-reference) (C++). Here VBScript:

   ```vb
   Dim Installer As Object
   Set Installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
   Installer.UILevel = msiUILevelBasic + msiUILevelHideCancel
   Installer.InstallProduct "example.msi"
   ```
3. ***Custom Action*** (running inside MSI): You can hide the Cancel button during the actual file copy of the installation by sending an **`INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA`** message:

   ```vb
   Dim rec : Set rec = Installer.CreateRecord(2)
   rec.IntegerData(1) = 2
   rec.IntegerData(2) = 0
   Session.Message 184549376, rec
   ```

---

### WiX Sample Markup

Not the greatest thing since sliced bread, but here are some quick WiX markup snippets to insert into your WiX source. I'll have one more look at this, but you can give it a try:

The actual VBScript that you need to compile into your WiX MSI (same as above). Save as **`HideCancel.vbs`**:

```
Dim rec : Set rec = Installer.CreateRecord(2)
rec.IntegerData(1) = 2
rec.IntegerData(2) = 0
Session.Message 184549376, rec
```

And the actual WiX markup (insert into your main WiX project):

```
<Binary Id='HideCancel.vbs' SourceFile='HideCancel.vbs' />
<CustomAction Id='HideCancel.vbs' VBScriptCall='' BinaryKey='HideCancel.vbs' 
              Execute='immediate' Return='ignore'/>

<!-- You can leave out this element -->
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action='HideCancel.vbs' Before='AppSearch' />
</InstallUISequence>

<!-- Required element -->
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='HideCancel.vbs' Before='AppSearch' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

If you get problems with `Before='AppSearch'`, maybe try with `Before='LaunchConditions'` or `Before='FindRelatedProducts'`. Strictly speaking you do not need the `InstallUISequence` element above it seems.

Astonishingly it seems it is not possible to disable the Cancel button in the dialog wizard (not sure if this is WiX specific, probably not), but you can hide it in the installation progress dialog once your setup is actually running the file copy or installation operation itself - which is hopefully what you need?

If you also want to disable the **`Cancel`** button in the setup wizard dialogs, then you need to modify the WiX dialog controls, which is more work. **FireGiant tutorials**: [**UI Wizardry**](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/ui-wizardry/) and [**User Interface Revisited**](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/).

Comment: thanks for your reply. Please check i have edited the question.

Comment: I ran a test with C++, and it seems to work if you put `HideCancelButton` in both the `InstallUISequence` and the `InstallExecuteSequence`. I am not sure why. I run them `After='AppSearch'` in both sequences. How important is it to hide Cancel, and can we ask why it is needed? Perhaps you need to change the dialog set?

Comment: Actually i have some task which can be ran after installFinilize and in this case if user click on cancel button the installer does not rollback. That's why i want to hide the button

Comment: What kind of tasks are these? I hope they don't need elevated rights? There are several problems associated with immediate mode custom actions after InstallFinalize.

Comment: They are some power builder commands which i can't run before installFinizlize

Comment: As long as they don't require any elevated rights they can complete. However, you should make all system changes in the transacted section of the install. I suppose those Power Builder commands are run against the database?

Comment: Yes. They run against database.

Comment: Often it is better to run such commands via the application on first launch after installation - if there is an application to launch. It all depends on the overall design of course.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your time. I am working on it to resolve the issue.

Comment: OK, good luck. An option to keep in mind perhaps if you find that your current approach causes deployment problems. I have seen some issues with immediate mode custom actions after InstallFinalize not running properly during silent installations. Please be sure to test.

Comment: Asmul, i am working on this issue and i have changed my custom action from immediate to deferred but i am facing some problems. First i am unable to access session object. I found the solution by passing using customeactiondata with another custom action. Second i have to access Session.database in my custom action. How i can do this? How i can access Session properties in differed custom action?

Comment: In deferred mode you do not have access to the session I am afraid, you are in a read-only mode where you can only access a restricted number of properties and the property values you have sent though to deferred mode via the `CustomActionData` mechanism.

Comment: Is there any way to access Session.Database?Or Can I send using CustomActionData?

Comment: To access property values in deferred mode you need to write them into the execution script via the CustomActionData mechanism. You can not set session values in deferred mode, only read them.

Comment: I dont need to set it. What i am doing is i write them in CustomActionData and when i am trying get it. It is a string. Not a Database object

Comment: Yes, it is a string. What are you trying to accomplish in deferred mode?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179170/discussion-between-umer-and-stein-asmul).